# Set cornerRadius for UISearchBar?

Tags: swift, ios11

I would like to change the cornerRadius property of an UISearchbar, but it is not working. I tried with:

```
if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        textfield.textColor = Color.text.primary // this is working
        if let backgroundView = textfield.subviews.first {
            backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 2 // not working
            backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? If i set the backgroundView to another Color, it works as expected (so the BackgroundView is here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like that background view has custom rendering code that forces the rounded corners.  What you can try is hiding that view, and manually configuring the textfield to look the same.

```
if let textField = self.searchBar.subviews.first?.subviews.flatMap({ $0 as? UITextField }).first {
    textField.subviews.first?.isHidden = true
    textField.textColor = Color.text.primary
    textField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Note that this could break in future versions of iOS if Apple decide to change the way `UISearchBar` textfields are structured.

Edited to not use `value(forKey:)`.

Comment: Never use private API! You could try to iterate through the subviews and find a UITextField whose corner radius to set (this approach _might_ break in future versions of iOS but is much less fragile).

Comment: That's not using private API, since there are no direct references to Apple's private classes.  I do however agree that a better solution is to search the subviews for the `UITextField`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine - so now it should be fine without using any private APIS or (because you just check for Textfields) ?

Comment: It should be fine.  Pretty sure Apple only check for direct calls to private functions and classes.